# Find a unit vector that minimizes the directional derivative at a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find a unit normed vector (direction) $d$ that minimizes the directional derivative, where $\nabla f(x^*)=(12,24)^T$.

My question: Is the directional derivative minimized by selecting a vector orthogonal to the gradient? Is so would $d=(-2,1)^T$

Comment: A derivative can also be negative.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @thisisme Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Comment: thank you for your help! by marking the green arrow does it consider to be solved? @gimusi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **directional derivative**, for every direction defined by a vector $\vec v$, is given by the doct product with the gradient, that is:

$$f_{\vec v}=\frac {\partial f}{\partial \vec v}=\nabla f \cdot \vec v$$

which is

- **max** (positive) when $\vec v$ is in the direction (i.e. positive multiple) of $\nabla f$
- **zero** when $\vec v$ is orthogonal to $\nabla f$
- **min**(negative) when $\vec v$ is in opposite direction with respect to $\nabla f$

thus the unit vector which minimize the directional derivative is

$$u=\left(-\frac1{\sqrt5},-\frac2{\sqrt5}  \right)$$